# Get full path from an opened file - C#

Tags: c#

I'm working with print jobs using `PrintSystemJobInfo` and this class doesn't have the path of the file (print job). So, I was wondering if there is a class where I can use the filename that is open (in memory) and this class return the full path. This file opened could be *.doc*, *.pdf*, *.xls*, *.txt*, and so on.

Please, someone can point me to the right direction or have an idea... it would be very helpful...

Comment: What you are asking is to find the title of a book without the cover. Unless you check all the books of the Library and compare the content, you can't find the it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Get Print Job Documnet Name ( File Address )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902406/how-do-i-get-print-job-documnet-name-file-address)

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you to find open file handles is to use the NtQuerySystemInformation call. [Here is a project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18975/Listing-Used-Files) that has this done as an explorer context menu. In this guy's case, he looks for files open in a specific folder.

You would then have to match the file name to the file you have in your print job.

By the way, this is not C# but you can wrap and call the same calls he is using. The rest is really up to you to figure out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `Stream` object that is a `FileStream` then just do a cast and interrogation:

```
Stream str = printJob.JobStream;
FileStream fileStream = str as FileStream
if( fileStream != null ) {

    String fileName = fileStream.Name;
}
```